# How does gensim calculate sentence embeddings when using a pretrained fasttext model?

Tags: gensim, word-embedding, fasttext

According to [this](https://github.com/facebookresearch/fastText/issues/323#issuecomment-353167113) answer, sentence similarity for FastText is calculated with one of two ways (depending if the embeddings are created superviser or unsupervised)

1. The mean of the normalized word vectors (unsupervised)
2. The mean of the word vectors (supervised)

But I cannot make either of those give the same answer as the sentence embedding

```py
from gensim.models import fasttext
import numpy as np

wv = fasttext.load_facebook_vectors("transtotag/cc.da.300.bin")

w1 = wv["til"]
norm_w1 = np.linalg.norm(wv["til"], ord=2)
s1 = w1/norm_w1

w2 = wv["skat"]
norm_w2 = np.linalg.norm(wv["skat"], ord=2)
s2 = w2/norm_w2

w3 = wv["til skat"]

# Using "raw" embeddings
((w1+w2)/2-w3).max() #0.25
((w1+w2)-w3).max() # 0.5

# using normalized embeddings
((s1+s2)/2-w3).max() # 0.18
((s1+s2)-w3).max() # 0.37
```

I even tried to add the EOS (as stated in the answer) aswell

```py
nl = wv["</s>"]
norm_nl = np.linalg.norm(wv["</s>"],2)
snl = nl/norm_nl

w3 = wv["til skat"]

((s1+s2+snl)/3-w3).max() #0.12
```

If we look in the source code, then `wv[]` just returns `vstack([self.get_vector(key) for key in key_or_keys])` i.e it treats `til skat` a single word.

I cannot find anyting about how sentence embeddings are created in the docs aswell.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In Gensim, you should use [get_sentence_vector](https://radimrehurek.com/gensim/models/fasttext.html#gensim.models.fasttext.FastTextKeyedVectors.get_sentence_vector) method, which was recently added.

Please read the docs and notice that this method expects a list of words specified by string or int ids.

Answer (score 0):

It's not clear from your question what sort of result you were expecting, versus what you got. However, note:

- FastText, in its usual unsupervised mode of modeling words (as with the `cc.da.300.bin` model you've loaded), *doesn't* truly define any particular 'sentence embedding'. That's not an inherent artifact of its training & outputs. You can choose to take the sum or average of a multi-word text's individual words' vectors as a sort of quick-and-easy sentence embedding. (And indeed, in the supervised FastText mode – not supported by Gensim – it's essentially *that* multi-word embedding that the class-prediction task targets.)
- `get_sentence_vector()` in Gensim aims to match the function of the same name in the Facebook Fasttext code, and you can view its (very simple) implementation – it just gets the mean of all the word vectors for the list of words you provide – at:

https://github.com/RaRe-Technologies/gensim/blob/ccffa84918dc13a6fbb5c82d6ba0e5e741266a3b/gensim/models/fasttext.py#L1132

- if you perform the exact same calcs, you should get an essentially-equivalent vector - but note that sometimes with these sorts of floating-point numbers, slightly different methods of performing the exact same abstract math can, due to limited precision & alternate optimizations, result in slightly-different results in the least-significant digits.
- with a typical model trained on usual texts, where spaces never appear inside tokens, requesting `wv['til skat']` doesn't usually make sense: it's asking as if `'til skat'` is one word. As a result, it will use FastText's OOV capability to synthesize a guess-vector for this non-word, from its fragments. The resulting vector – `w3` in your test code – might have some vague relation to those words' meanings, but *isn't* a "sentence embedding".

So, to get a sort-of 'sentence embedding' for the text (list-of-word-tokens) represented by `['til', 'skat']`, you could try:

```
wv.get_sentence_vector(['til', 'skat'])
```

(or possibly `wv.get_sentence_vector(['til', 'skat', '</s>'])`, but I'm not sure training would have even added the `'</s>'` end-of-text tokens in the unsupervised mode used to create `cc.da.300.bin`.)

Comment: My example could be more clear; I'm trying to figure out how gensim calculates the sentence-embedding. If it was the sume then the calculation `(w1+w2)-w3` should all be zero (or `np.allclose)`.

In the link I provide, they write that FastText embeddings of a sentence is the mean of normalized words  (when trained unsupervised) thus I wanted to know if Gensim `get_sentence_vector` was the same, which it seems like it is

Comment: So once you get `w3` via `get_sentence_vector()`, your comparison succeeds (confirming how `get_sentence_vector()` works), meaning one or both of the answers here helped resolve your question?